# iOS App list in the webpage

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes-app

I would like provide a search for the iPhone apps in my webpage. I have seen various pages where, once the user type the app name a javaScript made dropdownbox gets displayed where the top-hit app gets listed , so that the user can select one or multiple app from the list. I want the slimier environment in my webpage.

Did apple prove any api for getting the entire list of app? Also once the app gets selected by the user I should be able to get the appid that will be usually displayed on the appstore site url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTunes App Store API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689711/itunes-app-store-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the iTunes affiliate API for these sort of calls.

Here is an example call to search for all apps named "activeside"

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=activeside&entity=software
```

The documentation for the iTunes API is at the following URL:

https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching